# При попытке загрузить фото используя тип HttpPostedFileBase в модели проекта на ASP.NET MVC 5 IIS сервер останавливет проект без ошибок и исключений

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, iis, iis-express

Пытаюсь реализовать простую загрузку изображений из личного кабинета стандартного проекта ASP.NET MVC 5. Использовал видео туториал коих предостаточно на youtube.

1. добавил в модель HttpPostedFileBase свойство с атрибутом NotMapped. Судя по видео туториалу, автор не установил атрибут NotMapped.  Если атрибут не устанавливать - выдает исключение "ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null." и проект не запускается. Оно и понятно модель не соответствует колонкам в таблице.
   Код:

   ```
           public partial class Item
           {
               public int Id { get; set; }

               [Required]
               [StringLength(255)]
               public string Name { get; set; }

               public int Sub2Id { get; set; }

               public int? BrandId { get; set; }
               [NotMapped]
               public HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }
           }
   ```
2. В контроллере создал два метода Add.
   Код:

   ```
               [HttpGet]
               public ActionResult Add(int id = -1)
               {
                   if (id == -1)
                   {
                       return RedirectToAction("SelectManuallyUpdatedItemsGroup", "ManualPriceEditor");
                   }

                   using (var db = new ShopContext())
                   {
                       var item = db.Item.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
                       return View(item);
                   }
               }

               [HttpPost]
               public ActionResult Add(Item itemOfImage)
               {
                   using (var db = new ShopContext())
                   {
                       var item = db.Item.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == itemOfImage.Id);
                       string filename = item.OneCCode;
                       item.Image = filename;
                       string extension = Path.GetExtension(itemOfImage.ImageFile.FileName);
                       filename += extension;
                       filename = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), filename);
                       item.ImageFile.SaveAs(filename);
                       var returnUrl = Request.UrlReferrer;

                       return Redirect(returnUrl.LocalPath);

                   }
               }
   ```
3. Создал Представление на основе шаблона Create. Во Вьюхе добавил кнопку для загрузки файлов:

   ```
                       <input type="file" name="ImageFile" required />
   ```

Причем имя свойства public HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; } в модели должно совпадать с name="ImageFile" во Вьюхе, иначе кнопка работать не будет. 
Код:

```
         @model DeltaWebApp.Item

        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Add image";
            Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
        }

        <h2>Add image</h2>

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Image", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image, "Image Path", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="file" name="ImageFile" required />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }

        <div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "EditManualItemPrices", "ManualPriceEditor")
        </div>

        @section Scripts {
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        }
```

После сборки и запуска Перехожу в режиме Debug на страницу Add.cshtml, нажимаю кнопку "Выберите файл", выбираю изображение, жму кнопку "ОК".... И проект САМ останавливается без ошибок и исключений. Прошу помощи кто с подобным сталкивался, видит где моя ошибка или может дать полезный совет. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Потеряли атрибут [ValidateAntiForgeryToken](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc/8.6.php)

```
public class UploadController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult FromFile(UploadFromFileModel model)
```

Где вполне достаточно одного поля HttpPostedFileBase:

```
public class UploadFromFileModel
{
    public int InstanceID { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

Вы же пишете во вьюхе, что используете токен:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Image", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

В остальном код выглядит рабочим. Атрибут mapped - не используется в валидаторе, он нужен чтобы указать EF'у (если вы его используете) что не нужно в базу пихать это поле. А у вас падает с треском задолго до этого момента.

Вы сами же понимаете это:

> Оно и понятно модель не соответствует колонкам в таблице

Оно там и не нужно. (Если не хранить бинари изображений в базе)

Я правда не помню, чтобы приложение прямо падало на такой ошибке, но что без атрибута вы не попадёте внутрь экшена - это точно. И при этом никаких ошибок не вылетит. (Возможно, зависит от версии asp.net и окружения - я-то до продакшена это не довёл, видел как у меня локально студия реагировала в режиме отладки)

Comment: Если вдруг в экшн входит (вы пробовали поставить брейкпойнт на первой строчке?), то тогда оберните содержимое метода в try...catch, чтобы явно видеть на чём упадёт. Формально-то у вас в модели есть ещё и ввод бренда, наименования - но эти строки вы опустили (хотя если там и была ошибка - то я не видел, чтобы приложение прямо совсем складывалось, не выдав никакого эксепшена)